# Not able to delete apprequests using Http.Method.DELETE in facebook sdk for Unity

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using facebook's official sdk for unity in my unity game. I am able to send/get request using FB.AppRequest and FB.API(/USER_ID/apprequests, Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, MY_Callback) and the I am also able to read individual request using FB.API(/REQUEST_ID, Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, Callback). But I am unable to delete request using FB.API(/Request_Id, Facebook.HttpMethod.DELETE, callback). I am getting this error while trying to delete a particular request

> 09-23 17:45:05.798: E/Unity(3235): Web Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException:https://graph.facebook.com/MY_REQUEST_ID

Below is the exact the code I using

```
FB.API("/"+FB.UserId+"/apprequests", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, GiftCallback);
function GiftCallback(response:String){
Debug.Log(response);
var giftResponse = JSON.Parse(response);


if (giftResponse["data"][0]["data"].Value == "life"){
    Debug.Log("Life request found");
    FB.API("/"+giftResponse["data"][0]["id"].Value+"?access_token=Access_TOKEN", HttpMethod.DELETE, GiftConfirmCallback);
    Debug.Log("Delete request has been called");
    Debug.Log("Request id is"+giftResponse["data"][0]["id"].Value);
} else {
    Debug.Log("No life request found");
}
}
function GiftConfirmCallback(response:String){
Debug.Log("Gift Request delete confirmation");
}
```

Now I am getting all the debugs correctly except the last one which is not getting printed anywhere.

> Debug.Log("Gift Request delete confirmation");

and when I observed more I found the

> Web Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException:https://graph.facebook.com/MY_REQUEST_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

while if I run

> https://graph.facebook.com/MY_REQUEST_ID?accesstoken=ACCESSTOKEN 
>   in browser it gives me the correct apprequest details.

Comment: Are you using the full individual request id, `<REQUEST_OBJECT_ID>_<USER_ID>`, as described in the docs …?

Comment: @Rohit: here is an sdk with a fix for that, we haven't done a full suite of testing yet, but I don't want to hold you up from making progress. Feel free to grab this and let me know if it fixes your problem: http://unite-friend-smash.parseapp.com/v4.2.4/FacebookSDK.unitypackage

Comment: @aaron Thanks it worked on my Android device. Though it is giving me nullreferenceexception in unity editor
These are the errors:

NullReferenceException: Facebook object is not yet loaded.  Did you call FB.Init()?
FB.get_FacebookImpl () (at Assets/Plugins/FBScript/FB.cs:23)
FB.Login (System.String scope, Facebook.FacebookDelegate callback) (at Assets/Plugins/FBScript/FB.cs:115)
Facebook_Implementation.Start () (at Assets/Facebook_Implementation.js:54)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @Rohit: Within the Editor it requires EditorFacebook.cs for mocking.  Does that class exist in your project?  It also requires an internet connection to work.

Comment: Thanks Rohit! task made. Though it is stubbed out, we don't want things crashing in the editor.

Comment: @aaron this is the wrong place to ask this but this is quite urgent
Are frictionless requests are not supported in Android yet?
This is link of the real thread I have created.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180895/frictionless-requests-are-not-working-in-fbunitysdk?noredirect=1#comment30120232_20180895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the Facebook Unity SDK. As mentioned by Aaron it will be fixed in the next version of the sdk. If anyone else is in hurry to implement it they can try the latest sdk provided by @aaron in the comment. But keep in mind it is not tested a lot yet and not public till now.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue you mentioned. It only occurs on Android for me but not iOS. I used a simple workaround:

```
FB.API ("/" + requestID + "?method=delete", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, LogCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

`FB.API("/"+giftResponse["data"][0]["id"].Value+"?access_token=Access_TOKEN", HttpMethod.DELETE, GiftConfirmCallback);`

Did you mean to do this instead?
`FB.API("/"+giftResponse["data"][0]["id"].Value+"?access_token="+Access_TOKEN, HttpMethod.DELETE, GiftConfirmCallback);`

Right now your code is passing the key/value access_token="Access_TOKEN" as a url param.  You can also leave out the access_token param since the Facebook SDK will inject the one it got if it's not there, so this should work as well:
`FB.API("/"+giftResponse["data"][0]["id"].Value, HttpMethod.DELETE, GiftConfirmCallback);`

Update: the Http.Method.DELETE issue has been fixed in the latest version