# Frictionless requests are not working in FBUnitySDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

This is the code of my FB.cs file which is a by default code from unity fb sdk. If you see at line number 10 I have already marked frictionless request as true by default by removing the variable and just putting the value as true.

```
    private static bool frictionlessRequests=true;
    public static void Init(InitDelegate onInitComplete, HideUnityDelegate onHideUnity = null, string authResponse = null)
{
    Init(
        onInitComplete,
        FBSettings.AppId,
        FBSettings.Cookie,
        FBSettings.Logging,
        FBSettings.Status,
        FBSettings.Xfbml,
        true,//FBSettings.FrictionlessRequests,
        onHideUnity,
        authResponse);
}

/**
 * If you need a more programmatic way to set the facebook app id and other setting call this function.
 * Useful for a build pipeline that requires no human input.
 */
public static void Init(
    InitDelegate onInitComplete, 
    string appId,
    bool cookie = true,
    bool logging = true,
    bool status = true,
    bool xfbml = false,
    bool frictionlessRequests = true,
    HideUnityDelegate onHideUnity = null, 
    string authResponse = null)
{
    FB.appId = appId;
    FB.cookie = cookie;
    FB.logging = logging;
    FB.status = status;
    FB.xfbml = xfbml;
    FB.frictionlessRequests = frictionlessRequests;
    FB.authResponse = authResponse;
    FB.OnInitComplete = onInitComplete;
    FB.OnHideUnity = onHideUnity;

    if (!isInitCalled)
    {

        FbDebug.Info(String.Format("Using SDK {0}, Build {1}", FBBuildVersionAttribute.SDKVersion, FBBuildVersionAttribute.GetBuildVersionOfType(typeof(IFacebook))));

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        FBComponentFactory.GetComponent<EditorFacebookLoader>();
#elif UNITY_WEBPLAYER
        FBComponentFactory.GetComponent<CanvasFacebookLoader>();
#elif UNITY_IOS
        FBComponentFactory.GetComponent<IOSFacebookLoader>();
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        FBComponentFactory.GetComponent<AndroidFacebookLoader>();
#else
        throw new NotImplementedException("Facebook API does not yet support this platform");
#endif
        isInitCalled = true;
        return;
    }
```

No I am calling Init using this.

```
FB.Init(OnInitComplete, OnHideUnity,null);
```

And I then when I try to send request using this code

```
public static function SendLifeBack(){
FB.AppRequest
(
    "Enjoy a free Potion",
    ["USER_ID"],
    null,
    null,
    null,
    "life",
    "Free Life",
    LogCallback
);
```

}

There is not sign of frictionless request as there is no checkbox of 
"don't ask me again before sending requests to this user"
Even if I make the line number 10 as default as

```
FBSettings.FrictionlessRequests
```

even then it is not working. I have checked the frictionless checkbox in FBSettings too.

Comment: Which platform are you running on?  I know that frictionaless requests aren't supported on android yet, but they should work for ios and canvas.

Comment: @benp Ohhh is that so? Are you sure? I am working on Android.

Comment: @benp Do you have any idea if this has been sorted out yet?

Comment: Sorry, still no frictionless requests on Android.  We are looking into getting these in soon.

Comment: Does anyone know whether frictionless requests works on Android yet?